# what is arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')] in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and not able to understand what this command means.

```
arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
```

Comment: look for 'python list comprehension' on google

Comment: Takes an input with `input()` it will be a string, `strip()` removes leading and trailing white spaces from the obtained string. Then `split(' ')` splits it in a list of substrings by whitespace, and then list comprehension produces a list of ints (if your input was valid a sequence of ints)

Comment: `input().strip().split(' ')` is an awkward way of writing `input().split()`. (They're not perfectly the same. The second will do a better job of handling input `'5  \t 6 7 '`.)

Comment: @godaygo:  `split(' ')` does not split on whitespace; it splits on literal spaces.  If there are multiple spaces next to each other it treats them as distinct delimiters.  [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without arguments splits on all whitespace, treats consecutive delimiters as single delimiters, and ingnores leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I agree, but you know that I meant `' '`  literal space:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into python's list comprehension.

```
arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
```

Let me answer this with an example, suppose you input :

```
   1 3 4 29 12 -2 0
```

- the `input` function reads this as a string
- The `strip` function eliminates whitespace from both ends of the string,
- The `split` function splits the string into smaller strings with a delimiter:  (that is a literal space)
- In the list comprehension you can read it as :

  ```
  for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ') :
      int(arr_temp)
  ```

  We get a list of integers stored in the variable `arr` (`arr = [1, 3, 4, 29, 12, -2, 0]`). This is not an actual replacement code for the list comprehension but it might give you a better understanding of what it is trying to do.

Extra note : Apart from lists, Python also has comprehension expressions for sets, dictionaries and generators.